# XML accessing elements within the tree with Etree python

Tags: python, xml, element, elementtree

I'm trying to access information within a XML file via python Etree. The XML looks like this:

```
<events-data>
      <dossier-event event-type="new" id="EVT_4573534">
         <event-date>
            <date>20220816</date>
         </event-date>
         <event-code>EPIDOSNWIAI</event-code>
         <event-text event-text-type="DESCRIPTION">text</event-text>
      </dossier-event>
   </events-data>
   <events-data>
      <dossier-event event-type="new" id="EVT_4573535">
         <event-date>
            <date>20220402</date>
         </event-date>
         <event-code>EPIDOS PCT</event-code>
         <event-text event-text-type="DESCRIPTION">text1</event-text>
      </dossier-event>
   </events-data>
```

I want to access the `<date> 20220402 </date>` and retrieve the date, so 20220402. My attempt for it looks like this:

```
root_events = ET.fromstring(response_events.content)
for element in root_events.iter('{http://myapi/register}date'):
    print(element.text)
```

The problem: There is an unknown number of`<date>[date]</date>` before and after this date, but which is not within `<events-data>` or `<event-date>`. But if I try to list all tags, attributes or text of `<event-date>`, it's empty. Can someone explain me how i only access the dates within something like

```
<event-date>
     <date>20220402</date>
</event-date>
```

Comment: Your sample XML is invalid.  It needs to have a root tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you fix your XML to have a root tag, an XPATH query might work for you:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for event_date in ET.parse("sample.xml").getroot().findall(".//events-data/dossier-event/event-date/date"):
    print(event_date.text)
```

Produces the following output:

```
$ python sample.py
20220816
20220402
```